# Select distinct index names

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all indexes from a given table.

But, it looks like MySQL creates multiple indexes with the same name with all the possible column combinations when there is more than one column in the index.

So SHOW INDEXES returns multiple times the same value.

Is there a way to do a select distinct to get the index names from a given table?

And if possible that is not MySQL specific.

Comment: Are you sure the names are the same? Which column of the `SHOW INDEXES` do yo take? It should be `Key_name` which must be unique.

Comment: Yes 100% sure. Key_name is not unique when I do a SHOW INDEXES. But I have different values for Column_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME FROM information_schema.statistics
  WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
    AND table_name = 'your_table'
```

Comment: You're welcome! btw, `MySQL` doesn't create multiple indexes. It's just because `SHOW INDEXES` gives query result as one record per column per index.

Comment: Thank you for this answer @RGO. I've converted it into a full Java function for anyone who needs to know how to use it, and posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38670382/453673

Comment: @Nav But be aware that this query works only for MySQL.